# http get method does not supported when using datetime parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have Webapi service controller that supports two get method which distincts by parameter

## Controller

```
public class DailyRecordController : BaseApiController
{
    private IDailyBroadcastRepository _repo;

    public DailyRecordController(IDailyBroadcastRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
    public IQueryable<DailyBroadcast> Get(DateTime? date=null)
    {
        var dailyBroadcastList = new List<DailyBroadcast>();
        try
        {
            dailyBroadcastList = _repo.GetDailyBroadcastByDate(date??DateTime.Now).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }
        return dailyBroadcastList.AsQueryable();
    }

    public DailyBroadcast Get(int? Id)
    {
        var dailyBroadcast = new DailyBroadcast();
        try
        {
            dailyBroadcast = _repo.GetDailyBroadcastById(Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }
        return dailyBroadcast;
    }
}
```

## Config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When call `api/DailyRecord/2017-06-01` it hits to method with `id:integer` method, never hits the method with datetime parameter.

I have also tried to route attribute but not affected.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{date:datetime}")]
```

I fact, when I commnet out the second method with id parameter, the service returns
`The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'`
How can I build this controller with two Get methods that supports both datetime and integer parameters?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You need to have separate method names.Try giving names to the methods with [HttpGet] attribute on both of them.

Comment: I suppose I can do this, a video course that I had once made me think this way.

Comment: @ibubi, You should add your solution as an answer to your own question. That way you can get rewarded by those who found your solution helpful for similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by implementing a route constraint as shown in [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing#get-books-by-publication-date)

The route is restricted to the desired format by adding a regular-expression constraint to the route template:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{date:datetime:regex(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})}")]
public IQueryable<DailyBroadcast> GetByDate(DateTime date) {
    //...
}
```

> Now only dates in the form "yyyy-mm-dd" will match. Notice that we
>   don't use the regex to validate that we got a real date. That is
>   handled when Web API tries to convert the URI segment into a
>   `DateTime` instance. An invalid date such as '2012-47-99' will fail to
>   be converted, and the client will get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Define 1 get method with a string input and use TryParse to verify the input is entered in the correct format.

```
Get(string val)
{
   DateTime dt, int id;
   if (DateTime.TryParse(val, out dt))
   {
      //Filter by date
   }
   else if (int.TryParse(val, out id))
   {
      //Filter by int
   }
   else
   {
      //Error state
   }
}
```

Comment: Should I config anything else? I cant still get the value if I define method like this.